Wiring Hunter Skysail ceiling fan
I've searched and searched the web and I've read the related questions posted here, but each model discussed seems to be different and none of the schematics I've found match closely enough. For this model, the Skysail, there is no "receiver" box to wire as in most of the how-to pages. Just a white, black and blue (plus ground, of course) coming from the fan.
Here's the situation:

In possession of model 52370 Skysail Outdoor Fan.
It's a new installation, ceiling wired with 3 wires plus ground (white, red, black)
Two switches on the wall, one for red, one for black
Directions say connect fan black to black and blue to "ungrounded light", which would have to be the red as that's the only other wire. (What the heck does "ungrounded light" mean anyway?)
Wall Control has you connect black line in and out, and then directions read: "Connect grounding from the wall control to the ground control from the switch box", which must be simply the ground as the only other wire on the switch is green/yellow stripe.

So question: In connecting the wall control, what controls the blue wire from the fan connected to the red wire? The directions say nothing about it.
Am I missing something or are the directions just inadequate?

Okay, so I figured out the wiring after a brief exchange with Hunter fans support. This probably applies to several models, as my directions had images that differed from mine. But here's what I surmise after successful installation:

This fan is remote controlled. The "wall switch" is really just an on/off switch combined with a battery-powered remote.
The wall switch has only a line-in and line-out (VAC and Fan). Ergo, the blue wire on the fan motor, for the light, it absolutely superfluous. Do not connect the blue wire even though the directions indicate you would for a "two-switch" install.
A "two-switch" install, which I have but didn't attempt, is pointless with a remote controlled fan. If you try to hook the light (blue) to another switch (as in, when you have black, red, white wires from the ceiling), you'll only screw up the designed operation. It may work, but it will not be fully
functional.
Finally, the wall switch has a power on/off button, which controls the AC power to the fan, but it not part of the "remote". The remote buttons are the fan and light on/off, plus an increase/decrease button for each. It's battery powered, and unfortunately, when it's time to change batteries, you have to unscrew the cover plate and switch completely as the batteries are in the back.

Hope this helps.

Neutral(white) is some times called a grounded conductor, since ground and neutral can share the same bus/bar in the main panel.
A hot/live(black/red) could be called an ungrounded conductor.
More of the professional/regulation names than everyday names.

Thank you. It's confusing, then, to label the black feed as "Live" and the red as "Ungrounded (light)".  So, what, then, is the "ground control" wire at the switch I'm supposed to connect the switch to?

@Jamesckel   Does this fan have a UL listing?  The instructions almost sound like a bad Chinese translation.  If in North America electric devices must have an UL/ETL/CSA label/listing to be legal.

This is a Hunter fan, supposed the inventor of ceiling fans 135 years ago, so though I haven't checked specifically, I have no doubt. But that said, the instructions are very incomplete. They explain how to wire the fan motor for a 1 switch config and for a 2 switch, but then there's only one way to wire the switch control, that has only single black wire besides the ground. So what's the point of 1 vs 2 switch directions?
